# Unit Tests not running after Chrome 83 Update

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, karma-mocha, karma-chrome-launcher

[image]

I updated Chrome from 81 to 83. Prior to that update all of my Karma unit tests were passing successfully. Now, my HeadlessChrome unit tests are failing because Chrome never connects. Has anyone ran into this issue?

I am currently on a Windows 10 machine, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Exactly same problem with 83.0.4103. Last working version was 81.0.4044